# Cannot paste folder into Nautilus

Tags: linux, centos-7, nautilus

The CentOS 6 version of Nautilus offered 2 modes for displaying the directory/folder heirarchy:

- Graphical format
- Text format: as follows `/this/is/the/folder/in/question`

A great thing about this feature was that if I had a Linux folder path as a text string, I could set Nautilus to "Text mode", paste my folder path into the Nautilus bar, press the  key and Nautilus would move to the folder in question, displaying its contents. (Windows Explorer offers equivalent functionality)

CentOS 7 Nautilus (3.14.3) seems to be lacking the Text mode, and I am missing the ability to paste in a text folder terribly.

I have seen other articles regarding copying a folder "from" Nautilus, but nothing regarding "pasting a folder into" Nautilus.

If anyone knows of a way to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate the help.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK - in case anyone else is interested in this functionality, I've found a way to achieve this that is not too bad.

In Nautilus, when one starts typing, Nautilus assumes you are typing in a folder or file for it to search for, so it changes to "Text format"

...so what I do is as follows:

- type a char (eg. /)
- The bar changes to text format
- then I simply paste over whatever I've typed with my new folders structure text eg. `/this/is/the/folder/in/question`
- press Enter, and I am taken to the correct folder

hope this makes someone's life a bit easier ...like it's made mine :)